# ng2-bootstrap pagination pageChanged triggered multiple times

Tags: pagination, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the pagination in my angular2 app with the ng2-bootrap. am following http://valor-software.github.io/ng2-bootstrap/#pagination

my **app.html**

```
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
        <pagination [totalItems]="totalItems" [itemsPerPage]='2' (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="currentPage" [maxSize]="maxSize"
        class="pagination-sm" [boundaryLinks]="true"></pagination>
    </div>
</div>
```

my component

```
import { Component, View, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';
import { PAGINATION_COMPONENTS } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

// webpack html imports
@View({
    templateUrl: '/scripts/src/components/demo/demo.html',
    directives: [PAGINATION_COMPONENTS, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Component({
    selector: 'tabs-demo',
})
export class DemoComponent {
    private totalItems: number = 64;
    private currentPage: number = 4;

    private maxSize: number = 5;
    private bigTotalItems: number = 175;
    private bigCurrentPage: number = 1;

    private setPage(pageNo: number): void {
        this.currentPage = pageNo;
    };

    private pageChanged(event: any): void {
        console.log('Page changed to: ' + event.page);
        console.log('Number items per page: ' + event.itemsPerPage);
    };
}
```

its trigger the pageChange  event multiple time without clicking on pagination

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. But it's strange, on the demo page it works properly...

Comment: Why do you have totalItems and bigTotalItems?  I am having trouble with this.

Answer (score 1):

The event is actually triggered every time the `page` property of the component is updated (this can be done programmatically without any interaction from the UI).

In fact, this event is triggered three times when initializing the `pagination` component because of the following:

- **from the `ngInit` method**. This is part of the lifecycle of the component.

  ```
  export class Pagination implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, IPaginationConfig, IAttribute {
    (...)

    ngOnInit() {
      (...)
      this.page = this.cd.value;
      (...)
    }

    (...)
  }
  ```
- **from the `writeValue` method**. This method is called because the component is ngModel-compliant. When the expression associated in the `ngModel` is updated, this method is called with the new value. During initialization, the `writeValue` method is called twice: first with the `null` value and then with the `1` value.

  ```
  export class Pagination implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, IPaginationConfig, IAttribute {
    (...)

    writeValue(value:number) {
      this.page = value;
      this.pages = this.getPages(this.page, this.totalPages);
    }

    (...)
  }
  ```

That said, after this initialization phase, the `pageChanged` is only triggered once per `page` update.

**Edit**

After having a look at the code of ng2-bootstrap, I can't see how to do that without updating the code of the Pagination component.

Here are the updates you could do in this class (file `node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/pagination/pagination.ts`):

- Update the `set page` block to trigger events only when the `inited` property is `true`:

  ```
  public set page(value) {
    this._page = (value > this.totalPages) ? this.totalPages : (value || 1);

    if (this.inited) { // <---------------
      this.pageChanged.next({
        page: this._page,
        itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage
      });
    }
  }
  ```
- Update the `ngOnInit` method not to set the `inited` property to true at its end:

  ```
  ngOnInit() {
    (...)
    //this.inited = true;
  }
  ```
- Set the `inited` property to true at the end of the first call of the `writeValue`:

  ```
  writeValue(value:number) {
    this.page = value;
    this.pages = this.getPages(this.page, this.totalPages);

    if (!this.inited) {
      this.inited = true;
    }
  }
  ```

This way the `pageChanged` event will be called only once during the pagination initialization phase.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: what i do to stop it, bcoz of it my http call is called three times

Comment: I want pageChanged is called only when i click on pagination

Comment: is there any way to handle it

Comment: I had a look at the code of ng2-bootstrap and I can't see how to do that without updating the code of the `Pagination` component. I've planned to provide a patch to improve this...

Comment: I updated my answer to provide some updates in the `Pagination` class of ng2-bootstrap to tend to the behavior you expect... Feel free to tell me if this  fixes your problem.

Comment: I created an issue in the `ng2-bootstrap` repo: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/138. I'm looking forward to having their feedback ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger the 'pageChanged' event only when the user click on pagination, you can change set page block to this:

```
public set page(value) {
    var _previous = this._page;
    this._page = (value > this.totalPages) ? this.totalPages : (value || 1);
    if (_previous !== this._page && typeof _previous !== 'undefined') {
        this.pageChanged.emit({
            page: this._page,
            itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could try a custom pagination service instead of ng2 bootstrap, I just posted [this pagination example](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/Angular-2-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx) which uses logic like google search results.

**PagerService** that handles the pagination logic:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

export class PagerService {
    getPager(totalItems: number, currentPage: number = 1, pageSize: number = 10) {
        // calculate total pages
        var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

        var startPage, endPage;
        if (totalPages <= 10) {
            // less than 10 total pages so show all
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
            if (currentPage <= 6) {
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = 10;
            } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
                startPage = totalPages - 9;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                startPage = currentPage - 5;
                endPage = currentPage + 4;
            }
        }

        // calculate start and end item indexes
        var startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        var endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

        // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
        var pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

        // return object with all pager properties required by the view
        return {
            totalItems: totalItems,
            currentPage: currentPage,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            startPage: startPage,
            endPage: endPage,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            endIndex: endIndex,
            pages: pages
        };
    }
}
```

**AppComponent** that uses the pager service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as _ from 'underscore';

import { PagerService } from './_services/index'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private pagerService: PagerService) { }

    // dummy array of items to be paged
    private dummyItems = _.range(1, 151);

    // pager object
    pager: any = {};

    // paged items
    pagedItems: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
        // initialize to page 1
        this.setPage(1);
    }

    setPage(page: number) {
        if (page < 1) {
            return;
        }

        // get pager object from service
        this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.dummyItems.length, page);

        // get current page of items
        this.pagedItems = this.dummyItems.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

**AppComponent HTML** that displays paged items and pager controls:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1>Angular 2 - Pagination Example with logic like Google</h1>

            <!-- items being paged -->
            <div *ngFor="let item of pagedItems">Item {{item}}</div>

            <!-- pager -->
            <ul *ngIf="pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(1)">First</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
                </li>
                <li [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                    <a (click)="setPage(pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

More details and a working demo are available on [this post](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/Angular-2-Pagination-Example-with-Logic-like-Google.aspx).